# Why does this wrong variable error occur?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I can't compile my program, because I keep getting the error:

```
mine.c:40:44: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
             diamTable[r][c] = diam[r][c] +
```

The relevant code is:

```c
int getMax(int *diam, int m, int n) {
    ...
    for(int c=n-1; c>=0; c--) {
        for (int r=0; r<m; r++) {
            ...
            // Where the error occurs
            diamTable[r][c] = diam[r][c] +
                              max(right, max(rightup, rightdown));
        }
    }

// Driver Code
int main(int argc, char* v[]) {
    ...
    printf("%d\n", getMax(&diam[m][n], m, n));

    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone knows why I'm getting the above error and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `diam` of the function `getMax` is declared like

```
int *diam
```

So you may apply only one subscript operator to the variable. For example

```
diam[r]
```

In this case the type of the expression is the scalar type int. So you may not apply the second subscript operator for an object of the type int.

On the other hand in this call

```
getMax(&diam[m][n], m, n)
```

you are passing a pointer to the memory beyond the array `diam` that is you are passing the address of the element `diam[n][m]` that does not exist in the array.

To use `diam` as a two-dimensional array you need to declare the function like

```
int getMax( int m, int n, int diam[m][n] )
```

and call it like

```
getMax( m, n, diam )
```

In this case within the function the parameter `diam` will have the type `int ( * )[n]` and you may apply two subscript operators to the pointer.